# Why does Monthly Girls' Nozaki-kun get double-wide panels?

Tags: manga-production, monthly-girls-nozaki-kun

In most 4koma manga, the panels are about half as wide as the page, and there are two strips of four panels on each page. Take K-On as an example:

[image: k-on]

However, Monthly Girls' Nozaki-kun has panels that are about as wide as two of K-On's panels, and each page only has one strip:

[image: monthly girls' nozaki-kun]

Is there any particular reason for this? Is it the magazine it was published in? Is it a shoujo vs. shounen thing? Is it just a random whim of the author?

Comment: perhaps it's this author's style − less frames, more quality per frame, more freedom with speech bubbles